# How to retrieve real column name of multiple time used alias column in a view in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to retrieve real column name of multiple time used alias column in a view?

My table is

```
 ----------------
|colname |TYPE |
 ----------------
|Column1 |int  |
|Column2 |nchar|
|Column3 |nchar|
 ----------------
```

And this is my view:

```
CREATE VIEW myView 
AS
   SELECT  
       Column1 as UserID,
       Column1 as customerID,
       Column2 as name ,
       Column3 as gender ,
    FROM 
       myTable  
GO
```

How to get my view original name and datatype and column name using view ?

Expected output like

```
 ---------------------------
|REALNAME|TYPE |ColName   |
 ---------------------------
|Column1 |nchar|UserID    |
|Column1 |nchar|customerID|
|Column2 |nchar|name      |
|Column3 |nchar|gender    |
 ---------------------------
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048056/find-the-real-column-name-of-an-alias-used-in-a-view

Comment: already i tried that.but colname name is display  sequence