# Detect Sql-view structure

Tags: view, sql-view, information-schema

I create a view like this

```
SELECT        dbo.BaharInOut.BCode, dbo.Bahar.BName
FROM            dbo.Bahar INNER JOIN
                     dbo.BaharInOut ON dbo.Bahar.BCode = dbo.BaharInOut.BCode
```

And tried to get information from msSQL

1- way 1

```
SELECT        COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS VCU
WHERE        (VIEW_NAME = 'AAA')
```

the answer is

```
COLUMN_NAME  TABLE_NAME
------------ -------------
BCode        Bahar
BName        Bahar
BCode        BaharInOut
```

as you see ,  The BCode is repeated

2- Way 2

```
SELECT Name
        FROM    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'SELECT *   from  AaA ', null, 1)
```

And result more became strange

```
Name
--------
BCode
BName
BCode
Serial
MSeq
```

Any idea?

Comment: any one ... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Way2 just add simple "where" by using "is_hidden" column

```
SELECT Name,source_column,source_table FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'SELECT * from AAA', null, 1) WHERE is_hidden=0
```